# Using import-csv to schedule server restart

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm looking for assistance or guidance on how I could take a column in a CSV that contains a timestamp, eg: `5/21/2016 18:00` and use that to schedule a server reboot.  I'd have to split the date from the time, only I'm unsure how to approach this.

Right now I've got this code that outputs the two columns I'm interested in, I'm just unsure of what to do next.  Perhaps take the output of this function and pipe it into another function that does the reboot scheduling?  Also, could I run `Register-ScheduledJob` in a RunSpacePool?

```
$csv = Import-CSV (ls -Path D:\ -Filter source*.csv | sort LastWriteTime | Select -l 1).FullName

 foreach ($item in $csv){

 [PSCustomObject]@{
  Server=$item.Server
  FutureReboot=IF($item.FutureReboot -eq ''){"No data found"}ELSE{$item.FutureReboot}
  }

}
```

Comment: To the close vote, I'm looking for non-opinion based (I think you should do) assistance, for example:  To work with the timestamp, create a function that accepts a timestamp as input.  And so on.  I thought StackOverflow was a site that fosters learning.

Comment: use `get-date $item.date -format` to get the time you want.

Comment: My CSV contains a column with the timestamp of the reboot.  I'm just unsure of what the next step would be.

Comment: The easy answer, I propose, is to create the data into the CSV then use Import-CSV piped to Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString and use that.  Exactly how that is done is for another question.